# Issue accessing Custom Field in view file

Tags: c#, sitefinity, sitefinity-10

Whilst building my custom blog list view file (`Mvc/Views/BlogPost/List.BlogPostList.cshtml`), I am accessing a property added to the "Custom Fields for posts" setting in the blog section of the CMS.

We added an image field, and accessing it like `@item.Fields.BlogHeaderImage` in our item loop outputs `Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Models.ItemViewModel` on the page.

Am I missing a layer of depth or other methodology for accessing these field values?

---

The code is mostly just the Bootstrap blog list .cshtml file:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        var navigateUrl = HyperLinkHelpers.GetDetailPageUrl(item, ViewBag.DetailsPageId, ViewBag.OpenInSamePage, Model.UrlKeyPrefix);

        <li @Html.InlineEditingAttributes(Model.ProviderName, Model.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)item.Fields.Id)>
            <a href="@navigateUrl">
                <img src="@item.Fields.BlogHeaderImage" alt="@item.Fields.Title" />
                <!-- ^^^Line in question^^^ -->
            </a> 
            <h3>
                <a @Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Title", "ShortText") href="@navigateUrl">@item.Fields.Title</a>
            </h3>

            <div @Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Summary", "ShortText")>@Html.Raw(item.Fields.Summary)</div>

        </li>
    }
```

---

The class referenced by the string output on the page:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel(IDataItem item);

    public IDataItem DataItem { get; }
    public string DefaultUrl { get; }
    [Dynamic]
    public dynamic Fields { get; }
    public object Identifier { get; }

    public virtual string GetAddressString(string fieldName, string format);
    public virtual string GetBool(string fieldName);
    public virtual string GetDateTime(string fieldName, string format);
    public virtual FlatTaxon GetFlatTaxon(string fieldName);
    public virtual IList<FlatTaxon> GetFlatTaxons(string fieldName);
    public virtual HierarchicalTaxon GetHierarchicalTaxon(string fieldName);
    public virtual IList<HierarchicalTaxon> GetHierarchicalTaxons(string fieldName);
    public virtual string GetMultipleChoiceValueString(string fieldName);
    public virtual string GetPrice(string fieldName, string format);
    public virtual ItemViewModel RelatedItem(string fieldName);
    public virtual IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> RelatedItems(string fieldName);
    public virtual string SerializeToJson(string fieldName);
}
```

Comment: May be worth sharing some code samples so we can see what's going on, if you can't post the exact code make a good duplicate, with what you have posted it's difficult to give an opinion

Comment: @MarkDavies added

Comment: May be worth adding the model code as well, (might be worth reviewing [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @MarkDavies There is no model code. (this next part may not make sense, I'm unsure the exact terminology) The references for this are included in the  pre-compiled code from sitefinity, I cannot access the model in VS and don't know what it looks like personally, or this would be a non-issue. This question really needs to be answered by someone with intimate knowledge of Sitefinity MVC

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, yeah probably needs someone with some good sitefinity knowledge which certainly isn't me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to first check 
@item.Fields.BlogHeaderImage for null

and then do

```
<img src="@item.Fields.BlogHeaderImage.Fields.MediaUrl" 
alt="@item.Fields.BlogHeaderImage.Fields.Title" />
```